# How do I get a dropdown in yogiben:meteor-admin to populate with all values from my collection?

Tags: meteor, coffeescript

I have a collection called Academics. Each academic can have up to two advisors, who are also in the Academics collection.

I'm using the yogiben:admin plugin for my admin back-end, but the advisors field (which I call 'advisor1.who', see schema below) is not working how I want/expect - if I edit an academic, the only option in the dropdown for their advisor is the academic I am currently editing.

I'm also using Mongol, and when I go into the admin side, if I list all Academics, then only the current 10 listed are viewable in Mongol, and when I edit an individual Academic, only that academic is available in Mongol. How can I make all documents in the Academics collection available when I'm editing an individual in meteor-admin?

Here is my list of plugins, the ones that are of consequence to this problem are all up to date:

```
accounts-password           1.1.1  Password support for accounts
accounts-ui                 1.1.5  Simple templates to add login widgets to an app
alanning:roles              1.2.13  Role-based authorization
aldeed:autoform             5.3.0  Easily create forms with automatic insert and update, and auto...
aldeed:autoform-select2     1.0.5* Custom select2 input type for AutoForm
aldeed:collection2          2.3.3  Automatic validation of insert and update operations on the cl...
coffeescript                1.0.6  Javascript dialect with fewer braces and semicolons
dburles:collection-helpers  1.0.3  Transform your collections with helpers that you define
email                       1.0.6  Send email messages
fortawesome:fontawesome     4.3.0  Font Awesome (official): 500+ scalable vector icons, customiza...
iron:router                 1.0.9  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
joshowens:accounts-entry    1.0.3  Make signin and signout their own pages with routes.
meteor-platform             1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
meteorhacks:fast-render     2.4.0* Render you app even before the DDP connection comes live. - ma...
meteorhacks:subs-manager    1.3.0* Subscriptions Manager for Meteor
mizzao:autocomplete         0.5.1  Client/server autocompletion designed for Meteor's collections...
msavin:mongol               0.6.5* The insanely handy development package for Meteor.
twbs:bootstrap              3.3.4* The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive...
underscore                  1.0.3  Collection of small helpers: _.map, _.each, ...
yogiben:admin               1.2.0  A complete admin dashboard solution
yogiben:autoform-modals     0.3.5* Create, update and delete collections with modals
```

and the relevant part of the schema (in coffeescript):

```
Schemas.Academics = new SimpleSchema

    // other fields that work just fine are here...

    advisor1:
        type: Object
        optional: true

    'advisor1.who':
        type: String
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id
        optional: true
        autoform:
            options: ->
                _.map(Academics.find({}).fetch(), (academics)->
                    label: academics.name
                    value: academics._id
                )
```

This seems like it should work, since it is very close to the code from the plugin readme (which returns a list of meteor users as potential owners):

```
owner: {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id,
    autoValue: function () {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return Meteor.userId();
      }
    },
    autoform: {
      options: function () {
        _.map(Meteor.users.find().fetch(), function (user) {
          return {
            label: user.emails[0].address,
            value: user._id
          };
        });
      }
    }
```

and the admin config:

```
@AdminConfig = {
    collections: {
        Academics: {
            tableColumns: [
                {label: 'Name', name: 'name'},
                {label: 'Verified', name: 'advisor1.adminConfirmedAccurate'}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Anything else I can add that would be helpful?

Comment: It looks like your code in the autoform.options object doesn't do anything because it doesn't return. If you return the _.map line it should work.

Answer (score 1):

My problem ended up being that I was using meteorhacks:subs-manager to add subscriptions in my routes. Because of that, the admin package couldn't pick up the subscription for all the other academics I needed. Once I added a subscription in a top-level client folder, everything was fine. jamgold over at the meteor forums pointed me in this direction - so thanks jamgold!